# how can i use guzzlehttp to create Hub (centralized API)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, guzzle

I am creating API for different websites. but before passing request to website dirctly it will go through the middle layer server i.e. central server, then central server will pass on request to respective website. means all requests will go to central server then central server will communicate to respective sites and request data will be pass on as it is. All websites are developed on php laravel , architecture almost same. I found Guzzlehttp for request handling, if there is any other way to meet the requirement, please let me know,

also for laravel routing i need to call same function for all routes
currently i am having following routes

```
Route::get('users', 'QuestsController@getUsers');
Route::post('lists', 'QuestsController@postLists');
Route::post('add-user', 'QuestsController@postAddUser');
Route::post('update-status', 'QuestsController@postUpdateStatus');
Route::post('delete', 'QuestsController@postDelete');
```

instead of calling different methods of controller, i want to call same method for all routes like following example

```
Route::get('users', 'QuestsController@central');
Route::get('add-user', 'QuestsController@central');
Route::post('delete', 'QuestsController@central');
```

please help me for solution.

many thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what problems you are having. You indicate you want to use the same controller methods for different requests, and you provide the code that would make it work. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @DaanMeijer I think he is expecting some kind of proxy server which does some works and re-routes to different servers for response

Comment: you can check subdomain routing in laravel and `middlewares` can be used for this if its inside one app

Comment: @cerlin Boss, yes you got my point, i am developing a hub who will redirect request to respective servers

Comment: @VivekChaudhari I think you have to check subdomain routing in laravel.

Comment: @DaanMeijer, 
in code i showed the way, yes this is last fix, 
this looks ok if i am having few routes, but i am having 100+ routes which i cant write 100+ lines with same controller, i am just looking for alternative if i can group all routes and point to single method of controller

Comment: @CerlinBoss, yes i checked subrouting too , but no use for me,
thanks for prompt response

Comment: May i know the need of central server? (because it kinda sounds like a load balancer). And if you have achieved that, what will be the identifier to detect which request goes to which server?

Comment: So, you are really just looking for a way to use wildcard routes I guess? I'll whip up an answer :)

Comment: @CerlinBoss
actually all sites having same product, but with different brand name, kind of whitelist of product, we want to log all request coming for any whitelabel rather than logging on different servers, also other features will be there,
in every request header will have the parameter which can tell to resirect on respective server

Comment: You may need to read about [apache proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want a way to "bottleneck" all requests into one controller method, you can do something like this:

```
Route::get('{url}', 'QuestsController@centralGet')->where('url', '.*');
Route::post('{url}', 'QuestsController@centralPost')->where('url', '.*');
```

Now you have two controller methods which both take 1 (extra) parameter, which you can use to further identify the correct response. 
The controller methods would look something like:

```
public function centralGet($url, Request $request){
    ...
}

public function centralPost($url, Request $request){
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried this way too, but here i cant apply route validation middleware, it will accept any route either it is valid or not.
I want to reject the routes which does not exist
another way for doing this like
     Route::any('{url}','RequestController@redirect')->where('url', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');

Comment: Well, you could throw a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` when a route is accessed that gives no results.

Comment: I think I don't quite understand what the problem is. Do you want to apply route filtering or not? Do you want every url to end up in your bottleneck function, or do you want to specify which url should end up there?

Comment: yes this way i can show exception, but your answer will accept all urls
either it is /user, /user-hold or /blabla...., it will allow any urls, i want to redirect for specific urls, like i am having array of valid urls and if request is not belongs to url from array then it should be rejected, at last i need to write 100+ lines in routes but i am just looking for alternative

Comment: Okay, so check if the called URL is correct in the controller method. If it is, do your magic. If it isn't, throw a NotFoundHttpException. In what way does this not function the way you want it?

Comment: i am trying some other way like i will use middleware which will have list of valid urls then i will just validate in middleware, let me know if you have any suggestion.
thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132169/discussion-between-daan-meijer-and-vivek-chaudhari).

Answer (score 0):

I think that moreover you could want to use API gateway https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/. As Daan wrote you need one route which will be resolving all Services thorugh single entry point.

Then you can build service resolver and fetch data from interested service. You can cache response here as well

Comment: No. It's not about using 3rd party API. Its about concept of gateway. As far as I see, you're building API Gateway. It's a layer that fetch all the request and gather informations from different services. You can use it as a roadmap for services and as a caching layer for all requests' responses.